# How to remove top and bottom space of HTML video element?

Tags: html, css, html5-video

[image: picture]I came across this problem right now, while creating a video element:

The black-coloured box is the video (just a preview), and it's the same width and height as the other images. On inspection, I found out that the video took up all the white space above and below it.
I presume all videos have this, but there should(might?) be a solution for getting rid of it, in my mind .
By the way, I tried increasing the height, but to no avail; but apparently, the whitespace is calculated proportionally to the height of the video.

```
myDropzone.on('addedfile', async function (file) {
        console.log(file.type)
        if (file.type && file.type.split('/')[0] == 'video') {
            $(file.previewElement).find(".preview").children().eq(0).remove()
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
            $(file.previewElement).find(".preview").append(`<video width="80" height="80"></video>`)
            $(file.previewElement).find(".preview > video").one('loadeddata', function(){
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            });
            $(file.previewElement).find(".preview > video").attr("src", url)
        }
```

Comment: Please show us your code, without it we will just be guessing (my guess is that we need to think about various aspect ratios). See [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help on how to show us enough code to help us help.

Comment: ok, i'll edit.. but i don't have any consideration for aspect ratios (just wanna put it on the screen :)

Comment: The aspect ratio of the video looks different from the aspect ratios of the imgs above, which is quite normal, but you'll have to compensate to get rid of the whitespace above the video.

Comment: You're right, I actually did change the css for that at that time, I've updated

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've got the answer.. What happens is that the HTMLVideoElement has an aspect ratio, right? And this aspect ratio is maintained even if I resize the video using width and height. So if I specify the height I want, the width is automatically calculated to keep the same aspect ratio, and vice-versa. So when I give a width and height not pertaining to the aspect ratio, The video does take that width and height, yet still keeping the white bars on top of them